# Correct configuration of Arquillian and JBoss for a JBoss Domain Installation

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to setup Arquillian for use in a JBoss EAP 6.4 Domain (~= JBoss7). 
The Domain basically looks like this:

```
+-------------------+    +-----------------+
|Domaincontroller:dc+---->Hostcontroller:hc|
+-------------------+    +-----------------+
                          |
                          |      +---------+
                          +------>Server:s1|
                          |      +---------+
                          |
                          |      +---------+
                          +------>Server:s2|
                                 +---------+
```

I use the latest container adapter:

```
org.jboss.as:jboss-as-arquillian-container-domain-remote:7.2.2.Final-redhat-4
```

My arquillian.xml looks like so:

```
<group qualifier="s1" default="true">
    <container qualifier="s1">
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">myhostname</property>
            <property name="managementPort">19999</property>
            <property name="username">myusername</property>
            <property name="password">mypassword</property>
        </configuration>
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
            <property name="host">myhostname</property>
            <property name="port">5203</property>
        </protocol>
    </container>
</group>
```

Running an Arquillian Test fails throwing an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

I tracked down the error which occurs in org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.domain.**ManagementClient**

```
public Domain createDomain(Map<String, String> containerNameMap) {
  lazyLoadRootNode();

    Domain domain = new Domain();
#1    for (String hostNodeName : rootNode.get(HOST).keys()) { 
#2        for (String serverConfigName : rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG).keys()) { 
            ModelNode serverConfig = rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG).get(serverConfigName);
```

in #1 `rootNode.get(HOST).keys()` returns only the domaincontroller

in #2 `rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG).keys()` dereferencing fails, which is the ultimate cause of the IllegalArgumentException.

I suspect that the fact, that I do not see the hostcontroller in `rootNode.get(HOST).keys()`and cannot navigate `rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG).keys()` is connected with the setup of rules and permissions of myuser.

To account for that I gave all possible rights to myuser. And myuser belongs to the ManagementRealm.

Using the JBoss-CLI I also checked that the hostcontroller is connected with the domaincontroller.

I would like to know,

1. if someone has a working Arquillinan/JBoss configuration for a similar JBoss Domain setup?
2. if someone can explain why the dereferencing does not work and what to do about it
3. how myuser is expected to be configured? ManagementRealm/ApplicationRealm? Only on domaincontroller or also on hostcontroller?
4. what is the meaning of the group tag (~=server-group?) in the arquillian.yml and what would be the correct value for the qualifier? Same for the container qualifier.

Thank you for your comments and answers

Comment: What do you mean by "dereferencing fails"? Also is there a reason why you don't just run tests on a standalone server?

Comment: With the term "dereferencing fails" I mean that `rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG)` allways yields "undefined" as a result. So the hostcontroller node cannot be accessed this way.

Comment: The reason the tests should be run on the domain is that the domain is a mirror of a production JBoss domain installation which is the ultimate target for the software to be tested. Consider this as integration rather than unit testing. Also there are dependencies to other servers inside the domain and to systems external to the domain which cannot be replicated easily using a standalone server.

Comment: If `rootNode.get(HOST).get(hostNodeName).get(SERVER_CONFIG)` is undefined it could be a configuration issue. Make sure your `arquillian.xml` configuration matches your server. You can use `:read-children-names(child-type=host)` to check the host names available.